# R do.call object not found

Tags: r, object, tm

I'm trying to duplicate a text mining example on text mining Twitter data using R programming language found in 
Section 10.2 of Yanchang Zhao's paper [R and Data Mining: Examples and Case Studies](http://www.rdatamining.com/books/rdm/code). Zhoa includes a Twitter data sample [rmdTweets.RData](http://www.rdatamining.com/data) so the user doesn't have to get the Twitter data directly from Twitter website.

Zhoa's Twitter sample "rmdTweets.RData" is downloaded to my computer; the required R packages 'tm' and 'twitteR' have been loaded without error; and the working directory has been set to the directory containing "rmdTweets.RData", i.e. `setwd("F:/R/Test tm/Twitter_Data/")` .

When running this command from Zhoa's paper

```
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(rdmTweets, as.data.frame))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in lapply(rdmTweets, as.data.frame) : object 'rdmTweets' not found
```

Can you help me with this error?
Also, I'm new to R and am having trouble finding help on the do.call function written in 'beginner' language, so I can understand "rbind" and lapply

Comment: You problem is not related to `do.call`. The whole problem is in the error message: `rdmTweets` is not defined (in the environment). Have you `load`ed the RData file?

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the data file in first.

`load("rmdTweets.RData")`